# Do rewrites added with add_rewrite_rule() persist after plugin deletion?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I am developing a Wordpress plugin and need to ad a rewrite url using `add_rewrite_rule()`.

That does work. But what happens when my plugin is deleted? Does Wordpress cleanup the htaccess or do I need to do that?
How can I remove a url which was added using `add_rewrite_rule()`?

Comment: Hi Alexander, welcome on WPSE. Are you talking about `add_rewrite_rule` as by default there is no such thing as `add_rewrite_url` in WordPress.

Comment: Hi kraftner, yes I meant `add_rewrite_rule()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me say beforehand that when using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) nothing is written to the htaccess file. Rewrite rules are stored in the database and handled by WordPress internally on PHP level.

**TL;DR:** Rewrite rules do persist after plugin deletion, but probably not the way you'd expect it.

When using `add_rewrite_rule` these rules are added in the options table in the database. You then need to flush the rewrite rules via [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) (Visiting Settings > Permalinks and saving does the same) for them to come in effect.

Similarly when you remove your plugin that added the rewrite rules they stay in effect until the next flushing of the rewrite rules. So yes they persist, but they will disappear at some random point later on when the rewrite rules are flushed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and can I somehow remove the rewrites my plugin created?